# Trying to set TextView textSize programatically

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to set the text size of a TextView.

I'm using this code what I've seen around in a few places

```
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
TextView title = new TextView(getContext());
title.setLayoutParams(lp);
title.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.small_font));
title.setText("Cannot find our servers");
addView(title);
```

small_font is 12sp.

When I run the app, this is what it looks like (Cannot find our servers)

[image]

That certainly doesn't look like 12sp to me. How do I get it so the text is the right size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code:-

```
TextView text = new TextView(this);
text.setText("text");
text.setTextSize(12 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
```

or

```
tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12);
tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DP, 12);
tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 12);
```

or

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
    getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));
```

Comment: I want to keep the value in XML so I can change it for different screen sizes if necessary

Comment: Using PX seems to work. `title.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.large_font));`

Answer (score 1):

You are using scaled pixels(`COMPLEX_UNIT_SP`). It means that text will have equal size on different scrrens with different sizes. Try to use `COMPLEX_UNIT_DP` instead.